# Builds don't show up on iTunes Connect Test Flight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload an app onto test flight, but for some reason, after I get the "Successfully Uploaded to app store message", on the Builds tab no builds show and it is empty.

Is the service currently down or something? Because according to Xcode, the builds are uploaded (I get an error when I try to upload the project twice saying the build exists).

Comment: Do you see the build in iTunes connect `Activity` tab?

Comment: After uploading from Xcode it typically takes about an hour of processing time before the build shows up on App Store Connect. Has it been more than an hour since you uploaded?

Comment: Oh ok thanks. After trying to upload the app 10 times, it finally worked! I guess the wifi was slow that day or something